# Creating Rails Seed data with foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, belongs-to, has-one

I'm looking to create seed data that follows the foreign key constraints indicated.

I'm getting the message "undefined method 'create' for nil:NilClass"

My Commands:

```
rails g model user login:string password:string
rails g model account gender:string age:integer first_name:string last_name:string user:references
```

### seeds.rb

```
User.delete_all
Account.delete_all
```

## Attempt 1 to seed associated tables

```
@Jared = User.create [{login: "Jared", password: "password2"}]
@Jared.first.account.create([{gender: "male", age: 99, first_name: "Irish", last_name: "Coder"}])
```

## Attempt 2 to seed associated tables

```
acct = Account.create [{gender: "male", age: 99, first_name: "Irish", last_name: "Coder"}]
@Jared.account = acct
```

### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
end
```

### account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
@Jared = User.create [{login: "Jared", password: "password2"}]
@Jared.first.account.create([{gender: "male", age: 99, first_name: "Irish", last_name: "Coder"}])
```

where this part is nil

```
@Jared.first
```

try:

```
defaults = User.create(login: "Jared", password: "password2")
User.create{login: defaults.login, password: defaults.password, gender: "male", age: 99, first_name: "Irish", last_name: "Coder"}
```